# How to debug apache virtual hosts and domain conf?

Tags: apache, https, httpd.conf, lets-encrypt

I have added a new domain to Amazon linux server running apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
    ErrorLog /var/log/mydomain.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/mydomain.com-access_log common
    <Directory /var/www/mydomain>
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

Restarted the server
checked status
`sudo systemctl restart httpd` active (running) 1 min
But for whatever reason the default apache index.html is served
Directory exists for the new domain , index.html is there chmod 644 done

Error log for the new domain is empty.
Access log and error lod are empty

```
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root           0 Dec 21 15:26 mydomain.com-access_log
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root           0 Dec 21 09:50 mydomain.com-error_log
```

tail of host error_log is normal

```
AH00489: Apache/2.4.37 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.1.1c configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 21 15:02:24.161922 2020] [core:notice] [pid 73594:tid 140519198484800] 
AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

I feel a permissions/cert problem. Or one more thing letsencrypt crt has been installed for the new domain probably successfully

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ wget mywwwdomain.com
--2020-12-21 15:57:26--  http://mywwwdomain.com/
Resolving mywwwdomain.com (mywwwdomain.com)... 55.55.55.55
Connecting to mywwwdomain.com (mywwwdomain.com)|55.55.55.55|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://mywwwdomain.com/ [following]
--2020-12-21 15:57:26--  https://mywwwdomain.com/
Connecting to mywwwdomain.com (mywwwdomain.com)|55.55.55.55|:443... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘mywwwdomain.com’ is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘mywwwdomain.com’ hasn't got a known issuer.
The certificate's owner does not match hostname ‘mywwwdomain.com’
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$
```

55.55.55.55 - my IP address

How to debug further and fix this?

Comment: additional info DNS records were changed 4 hours ago, but propagated to my location, otherwise request from Chrome with new domain name  would not hit my single IP server

Comment: Additional info:

```

Comment: Or maybe propagation has not reached letsencrypt servers and I am trying to generate a cert for this new domain?

Answer (score 1):

If you added a new domain in a new file, make sure the new file is properly included in the main httpd config file.
You can get a list of the VHs apache is serving issuing the following command:
`# apache2ctl -S` (On Debian/Ubuntu), `# apachectl -S` (On CentOS/RHEL) or
`# httpd -S`.